# Keycloak permission how to control permission for certain records?

Tags: keycloak

Our existing non-keycloak permission has a concept of "context", which allows a user have certain permission to perform actions for a set of records, for example, the context is `customer A`, the user with the permission can perform certain actions for `customer A` records, but not `customer B`.

How do I achieve the same thing in keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

`context` is the authorization detail in this case, so I would put it to the access token as new context claim. That access token and context claim then will be used by your app/API to verify if user is authorized to perform requested action.

Use mappers on client level to add context claim. Context information are probably already stored somewhere (LDAP, DB), so you can read them with proper mapper. It can be easy - just (LDAP) user property or more complicated, when you need to obtain it from another system.